# Autoscroll UIScrollView to fit content like in native iOS Mail.app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

Native iOS `Mail.app` has got a great function when creating a new letter. The whole screen is a `UIScrollView` and the place for writing the body of the letter is a `UITextView` which scrolling is disabled.

[image]

As you type the height of this `TextView` as well as the height of `UIScrollView` changes dynamically, and `UIScrollView` scrolls down leaving some pixels above the keyboard for new text.

I know this process has to be done in the `textViewDidChange` method but while attempting to do the same, something goes wrong in my code - `UITextField` might sometimes go down, under `UIScrollView`. Here's how I try to do this:

```
-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {

    CGRect frame = emailTextView.frame;
    frame.size.height = emailTextView.contentSize.height;
    emailTextView.frame = frame;
    mainScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, emailTextView.contentSize.height + rightKeyboardSize.height + 20);

}
```

Any ideas of what is going wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I implemented my own sample project to find the answer. You should replace the names for  yours.

First, I will add observers to detect when the keyboard is shown or hidden:

```
- (void)addKeyboardObserver
{
    // This could be in an init method.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary* keyboardInfo = [notification userInfo];
    NSValue* keyboardFrameBegin = [keyboardInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    _keyboardFrameBeginRect = [keyboardFrameBegin CGRectValue];
    UIScrollView *_scrollView = (UIScrollView*)self.view;
    _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(_scrollView.frame.origin.x,
                                   _scrollView.frame.origin.y,
                                   _scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                   _scrollView.frame.size.height - _keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height);
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    UIScrollView *_scrollView = (UIScrollView*)self.view;
    _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(_scrollView.frame.origin.x,
                                   _scrollView.frame.origin.y,
                                   _scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                   _scrollView.frame.size.height +
                               _keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height);
}
```

Then, the textViewDidChange: method was changed to:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    UIScrollView *_scrollView = (UIScrollView*)self.view;
    _textView.frame = CGRectMake(_textView.frame.origin.x,
                                 _textView.frame.origin.y,
                                 _textView.contentSize.width,
                                 _textView.contentSize.height);
    _scrollView.contentSize = _textView.frame.size;

    if (_scrollView.frame.size.height < _textView.frame.size.height) {
        CGPoint bottomOffset = CGPointMake(0,_textView.frame.size.height-_keyboardFrameBeginRect.size.height);
        [_scrollView setContentOffset:bottomOffset animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Your method works only if UITextView is scrollable, not when its scroll is disabled. Also, I have a UIScrollView which I need to scroll as well.

Comment: The UIScrollView has the size of the screen?

Comment: No, its size depends on UINavigationBar and is customisable

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I'll definitely give it a try and report back with results!

Comment: I upload the sample project at https://github.com/luisespinoza/TextViewAutoScrollDown

Comment: The sample project has two targets, one with the old answer code and one with the new answer.

Comment: This. Is. Awesome! Thanks a lot. The second one is right what I need! Brilliant!